# add image to PDF form

Tags: pdf, overlays, forms

I have a PDF form and I want to add an image to this form after it has been filled.

Unfortunately both `{pdfpages}` and `{pdfoverlay}` render the PDF without the data entered.

How can I overlay Text/graphics on a PDF form including the data have been filled in?

Bonus: preserve the resulting PDF being a form.

---

[sscce](http://sscce.org):

sampleForm.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}[action={http://your-web-server.com/path/receiveform.cgi}]
\begin{tabular}{l}
    \TextField{Name} 
\end{tabular}
\end{Form}


\end{document}
```

*Remark* enter some data using a PDF viewer and safe them.

Image to overlay (test-passed.jpg):
[image]

overlayedPdfForm.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdfoverlay}
\pdfoverlaySetPDF{sampleForm.pdf}
\pdfoverlaySetGraphicsOptions{scale=1,  keepaspectratio}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (russell) at (10cm,20cm)
        {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{test-passed}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

expected result:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are SOL, at least until someone updates the PDF driver in graphicx.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do this with latex? Personally, I'd try doing it with qpdf; see, e.g. [here](https://www.suffix.be/blog/add-transparent-stamp-signature-pdf/). I think it preserves forms.

Comment: `qpdf` looks promising but it requires the overlay to be a PDF page itself with no possibility to move the overlay on the page from the command line.